# Google Pixel video camera keeps freezing and audio often doesn't get recorded

Tags: camera, video-recording, lagging

I have a Google Pixel running android Pie, and lately I've noticed that when I record video, the video intermittently freezes, and audio also intermittently doesn't get recorded, with an error message informing me that the mic is being used by another app. I've checked and no other app is using the mic. The video camera freezing happens maybe a few times a minute, and each freeze could be a split second up to a couple of seconds.

I've done some informal testing on CPU usage while using the video camera, and the top 2 processes (according to top) are the following:

1. android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service
2. com.google.android.GoogleCamera

The first uses about 60-75% CPU, and the 2nd uses between 20-30% CPU. Is this normal?

Another possibly related symptom is that taking pictures on my camera is also pretty slow, and it could take a few seconds while I wait for a just-taken picture to be processed before I can use it.

What could be causing the freezing?

Comment: Have you installed the December update? That update seems to have fixed a lot of issues with the camera.

Comment: Yes I have, it didn't do anything.